# Relative incremental ID by reference field

Tags: sql, django

I have a table to store reservations for certain events; relevant part of it is:

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
    # django creates an auto-increment field "id" by default
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)

    # Some other reservation-specific fields..
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Now, I wish to retrieve the sequential ID of a given reservation relative to reservations for the same event.

**Disclaimer:** Of course, we assume reservations are *never* deleted, or their relative position might change.

#### Example:

```
+----+-------+------------+--------+
| ID | Event | First name | Rel.ID |
+----+-------+------------+--------+
|  1 |     1 | AAA        |      1 |
|  2 |     1 | BBB        |      2 |
|  3 |     2 | CCC        |      1 |
|  4 |     2 | DDD        |      2 |
|  5 |     1 | EEE        |      3 |
|  6 |     3 | FFF        |      1 |
|  7 |     1 | GGG        |      4 |
|  8 |     1 | HHH        |      5 |
+----+-------+------------+--------+
```

The last column is the "Relative ID", that is, a sequential number, with no gaps, for all reservations of the same event.

Now, what's the best way to accomplish this, without having to manually calculate relative id for each import (I don't like that)? I'm using postgresql as underlying database, but I'd prefer to stick with django abstraction layer in order to keep this portable (i.e. no database-specific solutions, such as triggers etc.).

Comment: you lost me at `no database-specific solutions` :d

Comment: yeah, using a trigger would have been way too easy :)

Comment: I am confused by what you mean by relative id. can you please explain that. thanx

Comment: please, for comments in Python use `#`, not `//` (double-slash means "floor" division)

Comment: @julio.alegria yeah, I was replying a question about javascript, and I guess I mixed up stuff :) -- fixed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate always being the one that responds its own questions, but I solved using this:

```
class Reservation(models.Model):

    # ...

    def relative_id(self):
        return self.id - Reservation.objects.filter(id__lt=self.id).filter(~Q(event=self.event)).all().count()
```

Assuming records from reservations are never deleted, we can safely assume the "relative id" is the incremental id - (count of reservations before this one not belonging to same event).

I'm thinking of any drawbacks, but I didn't find any.

Comment: This solution works if, as you stated, "reservations are not deleted". If, in another application, they are deleted, this solution may not work as intended. Old `id` values would be reused. One alternative could be to have an `IntegerField` on `Event` that is initially set to `1`. A new reservation could copy this value as its `id`, then the value would be incremented. This would require the standard `create()` to be overridden or a signal listener to be written.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering using `Reservation.objects.filter(event_id = some_event_id)` should suffice. This will give you a QuerySet that should have the same ordering each time. Or am I missing something in your question?

Comment: Problem is not the ordering in itself, is to get a sequential id with no "gaps" for each reservation, to be printed on tickets. And I don't want to retrieve & count every record for each event every time :)

Comment: You will either have to (have a query to) calculate those sequential ids every time or store them in the table.

Comment: Yeah, the point is exactly that: which query to use, to calculate those sequential ids? :)

Comment: If you want to stay in Python, why not just `enumerate()` the QuerySet? If you're not storing them, I don't see how you can not calculate them as well.

Comment: @jknupp I'm not retrieving the whole set of reservations each time, that's why I want to calculate relative IDs database-side..

Comment: @redShadow Understood. You're solution is the most straightforward (non-database) way to do it that I can think of.