# Relative auto-incremental id

Tags: python, sql, django

I have a django model that represents items, each one can be stored in a specific group, like that:

```
+----+----------+-----+--------+
| id | group_id | ... | rel_id |
+----+----------+-----+--------+
|  1 |        1 | ... |      1 |
|  2 |        1 | ... |      2 |
|  3 |        2 | ... |      1 |
|  4 |        2 | ... |      2 |
|  5 |        1 | ... |      3 |
|  6 |        3 | ... |      1 |
|  7 |        1 | ... |      4 |
|  8 |        1 | ... |      5 |
+----+----------+-----+--------+
```

I need to generate and store that `rel_id` value somehow.

So basically I want exactly the same thing as here: [Relative incremental ID by reference field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618766/relative-incremental-id-by-reference-field), but dynamic calculation is not suitable for me, because I have to manipulate content of the table (deleting, updating, fetching a slice of the table, etc.).

What is the best way to do this?

At the moment, I use PostgreSQL, but I'd like to find a solution that uses django abstract layer, because I'll have to switch to MySQL later on.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for -- a way to create the rel_id column?  This should work in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT Id, 
  Group_Id, 
  Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY Group_ID ORDER BY Id) rn
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY Id
```

Here's the [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/644c3/2).

This should work for MySQL:

```
SELECT ID, Group_Id, RowNumber
FROM (
  SELECT Id, Group_ID,
    @row_num := IF(@prev_value=Group_Id,@row_num+1,1) AS RowNumber
     ,@prev_value := Group_Id as groupRowNumber
  FROM YourTable,
     (SELECT @row_num := 1) x,
     (SELECT @prev_value := '') y
  ORDER BY Group_ID
) t
```

And the [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/644c3/14).

Good luck.

Comment: Not precisely.  
What if i delete a row:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/94540/1
Last row should have RN 5, not 4.
I need to store the values in the table, and generate it when new entry is added.

Answer (score 0):

`class Item(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None):
        super(Item, self).save(force_insert = force_insert, force_update = force_update, using = using)
        self.number = Item.objects.filter(group = self.group).filter(id__lte = self.id).count()
        super(Item, self).save(force_insert = force_insert, force_update = force_update, using = using)
</pre> </code>`

That seems to work.
First `save()` fetches auto generated id, second `save()` updates record with `rel_id`, called `number` in this case.
Filtering with id_lte is used to eliminate race condition.